# "a reduction of " VS "a reduction in"

Tags: prepositions

> 1. That has led to a reduction **of** CO2 emissions by approximately 425 tonnes per year
> 2. That has led to a reduction **in** CO2 emissions by approximately 425 tonnes per year.
> 3. That has led to **a reduction of approximately 425 tonnes per year in** CO2 emissions.

I remember reduction/increase is always followed by "in" to mean something is reduced or increased. But here I see reduction of, which is a puzzle to me. I tried my best to offer 2) and 3). 
I am wondering which is the right one.

Comment: I think you have the right idea in 2 and 3.

Comment: @user3169 I am sorry I don't understand why 1 is not appropriate. Would you tell me kindly please ^^.

Comment: May be is it because "a" should be replaced by the determiner "the"?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, there is no hard & fast grammatical rule dictating whether **in** or **of** should follow the word 'reduction' in sentences similar to your examples, but rather this depends on the object being described and the type of quantity which is being reduced.

Usually *a reduction in* describes a result, where the subject is the quantity being reduced, for example:

> This has led to **a reduction in** CO2 emissions.

Whereas *a reduction of* tends to place the focus on the reduction itself, i.e. the action which produced the result, for example:

> **A reduction of** violent video games has led to **a reduction in** violent crime.

But then the above could also be written:

> A reduction **in** the number **of** violent video games has led to **a reduction in** violent crime.

*A reduction of* could also be used in phrases where the reduction itself is the subject of the phrase, and not the quantities being reduced, for example:

> Prepare the sauce from  **a reduction of** red wine & vinegar.

Comment: As for my specific example of talking about quantifiedly reduced amount of carbon emmissions, which one should sound better?

Comment: @MikePhilip Number 2 or 3

Comment: @MikePhilip I would choose number 3, or a hybrid of that and number 2: "[...] a reduction **in** CO₂ emissions **of** [...]" (replacing the "by").  We normally talk about "a reduction *of*" a quantity, or "reducing by", but rarely "a reduction by".